# Multiple Poisson Distributions Question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The number of flaws in a certain unit of material has a Poisson Distribution with mean of 3. 68 of these units are taken at random. What is the exact probability that at least 3 of the the units have more than 9 flaws?

I know I can't use the Central Limit Theorem since the probability needs to be exact.

Would I start by finding the probability of one of the units having more than 9 flaws and raise it to the third power to get the final answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find exact probability as follows.

The probability that a unit has more than $9$ flaws can be computed (first find the probability it has $\le 9$ flaws.) The latter probability is 
$$\sum_{i=0}^9 e^{-3}\frac{3^i}{i!}\tag{1}$$

The probability $p$ of $\gt 9$ flaws is $1$ minus the result of (1). Now find the probability that $\le 2$ of the units have more than $9$ flaws. This is a binomial distribution problem. The probability is given by 
$$\sum_{i=0}^2 \binom{68}{i}p^i (1-p)^{68-i}.\tag{2}$$
Your required probability is then $1$ minus the result of (2).

Comment: Wait, first I'm finding the probability of $\le 9$ flaws and then calling $\ge 9$ flaws $p$? That would be 1 - the probability of $\le 9$ flaws + the probability of exactly 9 flaws?

Comment: Thanks for picking it up, I had a typo.

Comment: No problem, I thought you just flew over that little detail and wanted to make sure. Thanks for the help.